# How to give one app sound priority over another

Tags: apps, settings, music

When driving, I am using my phone as navigation (Waze) and as music player (Spotify). I am trying to achieve such settings that whenever Waze gives me any voice commands, the music will be muted for that time. Is this possible? And if yes then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible for the user to do. I think that devs may be able to make their apps do this, but I'm not 100% sure.